# Regular Expression, Select word between two words

Tags: regex

I'm reallllly new to regex and I need some help. I tried figuring out myself but had no luck!

I am trying to select text between 2 strings (character for the last string)

ie:

```
word word2 :
```

I am trying to select "word2" between word and :

thanks!

Comment: what language are you programming in btw?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

another alternative is to use this pattern

```
(?<=word\s).*(?=\s:)
```

See [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Just to tell you, you might want `.+` instead of `.*`, since `*` is greedy

Comment: And if you can, your 'word' might not be specifically `word` per-say, so you might want to do `\w+` and then parentheses like this: `\w+\s*(.+)\s*:` to just capture any word first

Answer (score 2):

`/word (.*?) \:/` this should do the trick

Comment: try to remove the // delimiter like this `word (.*?) \:` this works (tested on regextester.com)

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you get the first group:

```
\w+\s*(.+)\s*:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that can find a guid inbetween anything guid anything  or same around  this is using dot net syntax and named capture with back reference. The anything capture syntax (.*?) is reused before and after the guid. So if there is an identifier somewhere in a Pat element or a App element this will find all of either.

```
[<](?<PatOrApt>Pat|App)[>](.*?)59358d09-8acd-4635-a019-1cbf9e1ed2db(.*?)[<][/]\k<PatOrApt>[>]
```