# Find words in between two words in regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have a file where I want to match a certain word between keywords using regular expressions. For example, lets say I want to match every occurrence of the word "dog" AFTER the keyword "start" and BEFORE the keyword "end".

```
dog horse animal cat dog // <-- don't match 
random text dog   // <-- don't match
start 

brown dog
black dog
cat horse animals

end 
dog cat // <-- don't match
good dog    // <-- don't match
```

Maybe regex has a pipe feature where I can get the text after the word "start" and before the word "end", then pipe it into a new regular expression? Then I could just search for "dog" in the second regular expression. I am new to regular expressions and have been struggling to come up with a solution. Thanks

Comment: You can't, basically because look behinds must be of fixed length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are matching "globally" (ie. collecting several matches that are non-contiguous) and you provide a stipulation such as "matches must all exist in a container" (in this case, between "start" and "end"), this generally calls for a construct such as PCRE's '\G', which matches only at the first attempted position:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|start)(?:(?!end).)*?\Kdog
```

See it in action at: https://regex101.com/r/uV7EjE/1

It's important to note that this uses some constructs that are not universally supported, and one specific to PCRE ('\K'). An explanation of each part:

```
/(?:
\G(?!\A)        # Match only at the first position, since the usual behaviour of regex is to attempt to match at each position. In effect, this ensures we only match immediately after the last valid "dog".
|start          # Or match "start".
)
(?:(?!end).)*?  # Match as few characters as possible, making sure we don't encounter "end".
\K              # Reset the consumption counter so everything before this isn't matched.
dog             # Match what we want.
/gmsx
```

If instead you need something with wider support for more basic regex engines, then you do indeed need to pipe a simpler expression, for instance `start.*?end` to match a complete group, then check its contents for all occurrences of "dog".

Comment: Wow thats a very clever and interesting solution. Thanks for the detailed explanation!!

Comment: Haha thanks, and happy to help! It's basically the standard "match between 'x' and 'y'" solution, but we can be even more clever if we know certain things about the input. For example, if we know "end" won't ever be out of place and won't exist without "start", then we can simply lookahead to see if there's an "end", eg.: `dog(?=(?:(?!start).)*?end)` which is simpler and more universally-supported :)

Comment: Good to know, seems like it can be very useful for finding specific values between html tags too.

Comment: Indeed, if you know what you're doing ;) But don't go around here touting that too loudly or the regex police will hastily shut you down!

Answer (score 1):

Update:

start(.*?)(dog)+(.*?)end

Test on the below link, here is a screen:

[image]

previous:
(please, note this might not answer exactly your case because it heavily depends on what language you are working)

Ref. 1 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035766/regular-expression-select-word-between-two-words)
Ref. 2 [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

It also depends on the language you are developing as the other comments are saying. If you can let me know where are you developing I might give you a better answer.

Also you can use this to debug https://regex101.com/

Comment: I wasn't able to get the words to highlight using that regular expression in regex101. I need this to work in a bash script, so I believe any standard regular expression will work, if that helps. My assignment requires a regular expression statement without using any other bash commands or tools

Comment: I see...ok, I will try to find and exact match and reply here. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Awesome thanks. I will check out those articles you linked in the meantime

Comment: eureka :)  "start(.*?)dog(.*?)end" that's your regex

Comment: I need to match every occurrence of the word dog. So the "dog" in brown dog and "dog" in black dog

Comment: ok...I think this should do it:   start(.*?)(.*dog)(.*?)end     -----start(any times "dog")end

Comment: start(.*?)(dog)+(.*?)end  -------------- + indicates one or more times, I believe this is the right one because it i match with two times the word dog in it. You can try ;) and let me know

Comment: Unfortunately that one doesn't work either. Also using the regex101 website to verify the result. Make sure the regex flag is only global :)

Comment: yeap  /sg    singel line and global

Answer (score -1):

I know you're asking for regex, but if you're using a certain language there may be more apt solutions.  For example, in PHP this function would work:

```
function getStringBetween($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

Comment: My point was: if you can ask for the solution in a CERTAIN language, people might be better able to help.

Comment: To whomever commented, deleted their comments and downvoted... an explanation would help.